# Method returning Future[Unit] containing nested future that is expected to complete

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

With this method

```
def taskA(): Future[Unit] = Future {
Future {
  print("Starting nested future")
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  print("Finished nested future")
} 
print("starting outer future")
Thread.sleep(1000)
print("finished outer future")
}
```

Is it possible to wait for the nested future to complete before actually completing the outer future?
This is how I execute this program:

```
print("Starting program")
val futureA = taskA()

futureA onComplete{
case Success(_) => print("future suceeded")
case Failure(_) => print("not able to execute future")
}

Await.result(futureA, Duration.Inf)
```

This is my console output:

```
15:18:52.357 [main] Starting program
15:18:52.563 [scala-execution-context-global-13] Starting nested future
15:18:52.564 [scala-execution-context-global-12] starting outer future
15:18:53.564 [scala-execution-context-global-12] finished outer future
15:18:53.566 [scala-execution-context-global-12] future suceeded

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do `something` *and then* do `somethingElse`, then you are executing two operations sequentially, where the second operation has to wait until the first operation completes. This is, for all practical purposes, exactly what *monadic flatMap* does. So, you should rather do something like this:

```
def taskA(): Future[Unit] = for {
  _ <- Future {
    print("Starting first future")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    print("Finished first future")
  };
  _ <- Future {
    print("starting outer future")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    print("finished outer future")
  }
} yield ()
```

The first `_ <- ...` will ensure that the first future terminates before the second future is started.